# Check with simple API request if account has received prior transactions

Tags: horizon, transactions, accounts

I want to check if a simple API request if an account has received prior transactions. I know that one has to do a transaction to "initialize the account" but how do I check if it has received any other transactions. More specifically, I want to check that the account has not received any prior payments yet.

Checking the balances on an `/accounts/:address` API call ([like such](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GCFXB6IURJZE7TVYZTTXTHKXIHLY75H4EOW6NX3UZV22SZE2DB24DGPT)) is not really an option for me because the address could have received transactions but spent it later. 
If there a simple APi endpoint that has a transaction count or could I check all the prior transactions of an account in an easy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`/accounts/:address/transactions`](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GCFXB6IURJZE7TVYZTTXTHKXIHLY75H4EOW6NX3UZV22SZE2DB24DGPT/transactions) endpoint to get a list of all prior transactions. You could also get [`/accounts/:address/operations`](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GCFXB6IURJZE7TVYZTTXTHKXIHLY75H4EOW6NX3UZV22SZE2DB24DGPT/operations) to get more details about the type of activity. That distinguishes `create_account` from `payment`, for instance, but since a single transaction may have many operations, there will be more data to retrieve.